# OpenGL: GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP and GL_REFLECTION_MAP

Tags: c++, opengl

I am currently working on a project in OpenGL.  Every time I try to reference GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP and GL_REFLECTION_MAP they appear to me as undefined.  I have included gl.h, glu.h, and glut.h, but they still appear undefined.  Any suggestions?

Comment: try gl.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, or whatever prefix/namespace/object there is in front of gl.enable() or gl.Whatever()

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: Those are the C headers, there are no namespaces/prefixes in C. You're thinking in terms of Java which doesn't apply to this question.

Comment: @datenwolf: I C plusplus in a tag

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: Doesn't matter. The OpenGL headers are C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything beyond OpenGL-1.1 is not part of the OS ABI (binary interface) specifications on Windows and OpenGL-1.2 on GLX (Linux is about due to get a revised OpenGL ABI)

Anything beyond that functionality must be loaded at runtime through the *extension loading mechanism*, even if it is core functionality. Most easy done by using the [GLEW](http://glew.sf.net) library.

Comment: Thank you very much, GLEW seemed to fix it up.